# Separate translation units

Tags: c++

While asking another question I was told about the possibility of using separate translation units (files), since my current code seems to be unable to compile due to it being too large.

Now I've been looking at how to use separate translation units, but to be frank I don't even know where to get started. If I had only a main.cpp file at the moment and I wanted to split it into for example 3 parts, where there would be one "variables1.cpp", one "variables2.cpp" and one main.cpp where it does the calculations etc, how would I do that using visual studio?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: You also can try compiling each source file into an object file separately and then linking them together. Maybe this could reduce memory usage.

Comment: @Tyler the link is rather irrelevant to the question. You can have several classes in one translation unit as well as several translation units without any OOP

Comment: @ForceBru That's exactly what "separate translation units" means.

Comment: @melpomene, yeah, I meant there may be no need to split one file into multiple files.

Comment: @ForceBru That doesn't make sense. How can you compile each file separately if you only have one source file that you don't split up?

Comment: @melpomene, I didn't notice that the OP had _only a main.cpp file at the moment _ at first, oops...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the main tasks of a programmer, how to structure the code in such a way that the logic of the code becomes clear by this "separation". Some will use one class/one file.

I think this question needs a very detailed answer. Maybe you should read this article:
[Organizing Code Files in C and C++](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798)

> Splitting any reasonably-sized project up buys you some advantages,
>   the most significant of which are the following:
>
> *Speed up compilation*
>   - most compilers work on a file at a time. So if all your 10000 lines of code is in one file, and you change one line, then you have to
>   recompile 10000 lines of code. On the other hand, if your 10000 lines
>   of code are spread evenly across 10 files, then changing one line will
>   only require 1000 lines of code to be recompiled. The 9000 lines in
>   the other 9 files will not need recompiling. (Linking time is
>   unaffected.)
>
> *Increase organization* - Splitting your code along logical lines will
>   make it easier for you (and any other programmers on the project) to
>   find functions, variables, struct/class declarations, and so on. Even
>   with the ability to jump directly to a given identifier that is
>   provided in many editors and development environments (such as
>   Microsoft Visual C++), there will always be times when you need to
>   scan the code manually to look for something. Just as splitting the
>   code up reduces the amount of code you need to recompile, it also
>   reduces the amount of code you need to read in order to find
>   something. Imagine that you need to find a fix you made to the sound
>   code a few weeks ago. If you have one large file called GAME.C, that's
>   potentially a lot of searching. If you have several small files called
>   GRAPHICS.C, MAINLOOP.C, SOUND.C, and INPUT.C, you know where to look,
>   cutting your browsing time by 3/4.
>
> *Facilitate code reuse* - If your code is carefully split up into
>   sections that operate largely independently of each other, this lets
>   you use that code in another project, saving you a lot of rewriting
>   later. There is a lot more to writing reusable code than just using a
>   logical file organization, but without such an organization it is very
>   difficult to know which parts of the code work together and which do
>   not. Therefore putting subsystems and classes in a single file or
>   carefully delineated set of files will help you later if you try to
>   use that code in another project.
>
> *Share code between projects* - The principle here is the same as with
>   the reuse issue. By carefully separating code into certain files, you
>   make it possible for multiple projects to use some of the same code
>   files without duplicating them. The benefit of sharing a code file
>   between projects rather than just using copy-and-paste is that any bug
>   fixes you make to that file or files from one project will affect the
>   other project, so both projects can be sure of using the most
>   up-to-date version.
>
> *Split coding responsibilities among programmers* - For really large
>   projects, this is perhaps the main reason for separating code into
>   multiple files. It isn't practical for more than one person to be
>   making changes to a single file at any given time. Therefore you would
>   need to use multiple files so that each programmer can be working on a
>   separate part of the code without affecting the file that the other
>   programmers are editing. Of course, there still have to be checks that
>   2 programmers don't try altering the same file; configuration
>   management systems and version control systems such as CVS or MS
>   SourceSafe help you here.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I ussualy tend to give a short answer as fast as possible(the person who asks the question needs the answer) and than edit it to improve it.

Comment: I fear there's no quick answer to this one. OP isn't providing any details but it sounds like they have a single 100,000-line `main` function with 60,000 variables in it.

Comment: Thanks Heto, but I'm sure not that fixes it.. I've tried to put my variables into header files (2 of them, at the moment) and to #include them into the main.cpp. Could very well be that I'm getting this wrong, but isn't that what the article tells me to do?

@melpomene, that is indeed the case.. I'm not sure what details exactly you want to hear, what I've created is a genetic algorithm that was working fine so far, but now that I've doubled the amount of variables it seems to no longer be able to compile, so I'd guess it's gotten too big.

Comment: @Milan As several people have been telling you, stop using header files. `#include` will do nothing to fix your problem. You need separate translation units.

Comment: @Melpomene, I know, I'm well aware by now. It's just that the article that was posted as an answer was mostly focused on headers and including them.

Comment: `#include` has nothing to do with compilation itself, those are "solved" ahead of compilation during preprocessing time. So whatever you #include is being compiled as single file in the end. Check the compiler options to get preprocessed file, to get idea what the compiler is dealing with. (-E usually IIRC?). The headers are important for you to specify only declarations of external symbols, which will be visible to current .cpp during linking time. Content (implementation?) of those declared symbols is done then in other .cpp. How to apply it to your case is impossible to say w/o some sample.

Comment: @Milan I want to see (at least parts of) your code. It's very hard to make any recommendations in a vacuum. (However, the general vibe I'm getting is that you've created a horrible mess that no one else is able to understand, let alone maintain/fix. (60,000 variables? What the hell?!))

Comment: @melpomene: it's "genetic algorithm", so I guess the source itself is produced by code, so indeed it must be total mess. Actually I believe the proper fix will be to fix the generator itself to be more clever and create reusable functions + split them between several .cpp files. Or to get different C compiler, which would be able to deal with the current source.

Comment: @melpomene Heh, that could very well be the case.. The code isn't even that complicated to be honest with you. It was working perfectly before, all I'm really asking is whether there's a way to be able to include more variables without hitting some apparent limit where the program will no longer compile.. I posted a pastebin on the other thread of where the variables are used by the way.

Comment: @Milan: put some code to be able to give you a specific answer. You've asked a general question -> you've recieved a general answer. But in my opinion the article covers the basics: why to split and how to split.

Comment: @ped7g How it works is that the calculations are for example outcome1 = variable1 * gene1 + variable2 * gene2, outcome 2 = variable3 * gene1 + variable4 * gene2 etc.

Comment: The link is http://pastebin.com/mrNhDu4L. My answer: Throw it all away and start again with some kind of structure. Maybe take a programming course or two.

Comment: @melpomene Haha, you're probably right there. There is a very definitive structure to me, and it is really easy for me to add both variables and to expand the "formula", so to say. Like I said, the problem isn't with the formula or anything, that's been tested many many times with many different sorts of variables. It's just that right now I'm apparently adding in too many variables into the program, and it won't compile. I was hoping someone might know how to work around that in a way that wouldn't mean rewriting the entire program.

Comment: Try different compiler. Or get a real programmer, this structure would be probably "easy" to rewrite in general way, with configuration of genes/variables in text files, just executing general calculator afterwards... ("easy" may still take few months of coding). But I hope this source will evaporate soon and never ever emerge again anywhere. :D

Comment: @Ped7g I'm indeed not a real programmer, but I really don't understand the problem. The code not only runs well but it runs quite quickly, with population size of 1000, 80 genes per individual and 200 calculations per individual it will run a single generation within a second. I don't intend for it to be used by anyone else, so the structure not seeming easy to others is no problem to me :) Plus, this way I can add new variables/calculations really fast :) Anyway, are there any compilers that you'd recommend?

Comment: I'm sure I could beat it in speed easily... but as I wrote, it would take some development time (at least a week for me I think). This is way beyond the scope of "answering something for fun at SO". About compilers.. I have no idea what HW/OS/compiler you are using now (nor do I want to know), but being sarcastic smartass: head to linux+clang.. it will either work, or you can fix the sources and propose a patch to clang developers. (or search the internet for C compilers) (or rewrite that stuff in decent way).

Comment: @Ped7g Haha, I don't doubt you could beat it in speed/readability/any aspect. Just saying it hasn't given me any problems so far :) I'm on WIndows 10, Visual Studio 2015 with I guess the standard compiler. And to be honest with you I was hoping for a fix like "install compiler xx into visual studio", I'm not nearly hardcore enough to actually switch to Linux etc. Thanks anyway, I appreciate you taking the time to answer questions like this, especially given that my code is apparently so painful to look at.

Comment: @Milan (edit: misread something .. I'm too tired, sorry... deleting crap) ... I have no idea what is current status of windows C compilers, I don't follow MS windows platform for a decade+, still surprises me it's used.

Comment: @Ped7g Edit: Haha fair enough. Thanks for your help anyway, as a MS windows platform user I can say that for me it's simply because it's what I grew up with and am used to.